# JavaScript add class once trough scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add a class navbar-fixed-top to navigation when user scrolls i made this script:

```
var nav;
function yScroll(){
    nav = document.getElementById('nav');
    yPos = window.pageYOffset;
    if(yPos > 150){
        nav.className = nav.className + " navbar-fixed-top";
    } else {
        nav.className = nav.className - " navbar-fixed-top";
    }
}
window.addEventListener("scroll", yScroll);
```

But the problem is that it will always give a class to nav when yPos > 150.

So as i continue to scroll up and down in inspect element it adds a lot of same classes. How to add he class just once, or you have other solution. i have 2 navbar and i want just 2 to be fixed after user scrolled so he cant anymore see the top one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using jQuery so use:

```
nav.addClass("navbar-fixed-top")
```

and

```
nav.removeClass("navbar-fixed-top")
```

I think this maybe what you want:

```
var nav;
function yScroll(){
    nav = $('#nav');
    yPos = window.pageYOffset;
    nav.removeClass("navbar-fixed-top");
    if(yPos > 150){
        nav.addClass("navbar-fixed-top");
    }
}
window.addEventListener("scroll", yScroll);
```

Comment: Correct, jQuery is smart enough to add classes only once.

Comment: but why mix jQuery with non-jQuery javascript?

Comment: As i scroll down in console i see more and more errors, Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
124main.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a functionmain.js:5 yScroll

Comment: Forgot to change the line `nav = document.getElementById('nav');` to `nav = $('#nav');` this will create the variable as a Jquery object.

Answer (score 1):

Check if it already has that class like this....

```
var nav;
function yScroll(){
    nav = document.getElementById('nav');
    yPos = window.pageYOffset;
    var isThereClass = nav.className.indexOf("navbar-fixed-top");
    if(yPos > 150 && isThereClass == -1){
        nav.className = nav.className + " navbar-fixed-top";
    } else if (yPos < 150 && isThereClass != -1) {
        nav.className = nav.className - " navbar-fixed-top";
    }
}
window.addEventListener("scroll", yScroll);
```